# CVAT API Filter Tasks by Project ID

Tags: python, cvat

So I want to list the tasks in CVAT using the API but to filter the tasks for specific project (using its project id or name). lookin at the docs for tasks.list.api, I try to use `filter` argument but cant make it work. As you see I was able to retreive the project I am looking for by `client.projects.retreive(id)`

```
    project = client.projects.retrieve(3)
    print(f"Found project {project.id}")

    project_id = "3"
    filter_json = json.dumps({"project_id": project_id})
    tasks = client.tasks.api.list(filter=filter_json)
```

console output

```
Found project 3
.
.
.
.
.
cvat_sdk.api_client.exceptions.ApiException: Status Code: 400
Reason: Bad Request
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Allow': 'GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS', 'Content-Length': '68', 'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.cvat+json', 'Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy': 'same-origin', 'Date': 'Thu, 27 Jul 2023 18:27:31 GMT', 'Referrer-Policy': 'same-origin', 'Server': 'nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)', 'Vary': 'Accept, Origin', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'X-Frame-Options': 'DENY', 'X-Request-Id': '6fa1519f-07ee-47cb-958a-00c33bcfec34'})
HTTP response body: ["filter: project_id operation with 3 arguments is not implemented"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `list(project_id=project_id)`.
However the `filter` option is poorly documented and I filed [an issue](https://github.com/opencv/cvat/issues/6622).